# magento2 data migration error Exception #0 (BadMethodCallException): Missing required argument $options

Tags: magento2, customer, view, data

[image]

after migrating customer data when i click on view customer view data it was shown above error, please help me to resolve

Answer (score 2):

If you used Data Migration Tool it is possible that some unwanted customer attributes were migrated. These attributes usually create by third party extensions. So the solution could be to find these attributes in eav_attribute table then include them into  tag in eav-attribute-groups.xml file of the tool.

Comment: +1. Also - I went into eav_attribute and removed some attributes from 3rd-party modules of the old M1 site.